# Angular: binding not working with Indexed Array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I choose to work with this data structure :

```
let disponibilities = [
  "2019-7-15" : {id: 1, ...},
  "2019-7-16" : {id: 2, ...},
  "2019-7-20" : {id: 3, ...}
]
```

But in the template binding doesn't work,It behave as it was an empty array, I tested it with this code :

```
{{disponibilites.length}} // result: 0
{{disponibilites | json}} // result: []
// ngFor not showing any data.
```

I'm asking why this behavior and what data structure I have to adapt in this case (indexed Array of objects)?

Comment: `[
  {"2019-7-15" : {id: 1}},
  {"2019-7-16" : {id: 2}},
  {"2019-7-20" : {id: 3}}
]` is valid, but your data right now is not.

Answer (score 0):

- typo error, change `disponibilites.length` to `disponibilities.length`.
- `let disponibilities = ["2019-7-15" : {id: 1, ...},...]` 
  is wrong data structor (its not `array` nor `object`). use: 
  `let disponibilities = {"2019-7-15" : {id: 1, ...},...}`
  instead.
- use `Object.keys(disponibilites).length` instead of `disponibilites.length`

Answer (score 0):

Since your array is an assoc array, you could use Object.keys to bind your array. For example:

```
// typescript file. define a property for Object.keys
objectKeys = Object.keys;
```

```
// html file, use objectKeys for binding
<ng-container ngFor="let key of objectKeys(arrayName)">
   <tr>
      <td>{{ arrayName[key].propertyName1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ arrayName[key].propertyName2 }}</td>
      ...
   </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
disponibilities = {
  "2019-7-15" : {id: 1, ...},
  "2019-7-16" : {id: 2, ...},
  "2019-7-20" : {id: 3, ...}
}
```

Using ES6 ComputedPropertyName you could also set your date key with a variable:

```
let date1 = "2019-7-15";
disponibilities = {
  [date1] : {id: 1, ...},
  "2019-7-16" : {id: 2, ...},
  "2019-7-20" : {id: 3, ...}
}
```

Declare your array before the constructor without the `let` or with `this` if in constructor for Angular to bind it correctly.

If you need to loop over it, you need to make `Object.keys` available in the template:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-myview',
  template: `<div *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(disponibilities)">{{key + ' : ' + disponibilities[key]}}</div>`
})

export class MyComponent {
  objectKeys = Object.keys;

  disponibilities = {
    "2019-7-15" : {id: 1, ...},
    "2019-7-16" : {id: 2, ...},
    "2019-7-20" : {id: 3, ...}
  }

  constructor(){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is not a good data structure because even if it was a valid struct in JavaScript, you can't access your objects by the keys easily. You could try something like:

```js
let disponibilities = [
  { date: "2019-7-15", id: 1, ...},
  { date: "2019-7-16", id: 2, ...},
  { date: "2019-7-20", id: 3, ...},
]
```